# How can I evaluate MS Build Variables?

Tags: msbuild

For example, if I wanted to output the value of

```
  $(SolutionRoot)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In a Target, use Task 'Message'

```
  <Target Name="PrintCurrentSettings">
    <Message Text="   $SolutionRoot     : $(SolutionRoot)"/>
  </Target>
```

Comment: and is it going to show up in the Output - Build - Team Foundation?

Comment: I typically run my builds from the command line; these output messages show up in the console fine (in dark grey).  I assume if you override standard targets and run builds in the IDE or via TFSBuild they'd also show - it's the same mechanism.